# How to change an empty star glyphicon button to star glyphicon button onclick with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

This seems to change the glyphicon only when I click glyphicon itself. I want it to change when I click the button.

```
<script>       
      $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
});     
    </script>

<button class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: You need to add the `glyphicon-star` class to span on click of the button also. In the snippet, it has only been done on click of the span

Comment: Sorry, I'm really a noob to all this. I couldn't understand what I must do.

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery to add click functionality to button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
    });     
})
```

You have to bind the event on the button, not only the icon, else it will be triggered only clicking the star.